# Why Does LiveData return null when using get() instead of Transforamtion.switchmap?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

recently I have had used MVVM architecture and Livedata with observer. I could use Transformation.switchmap() . but I wanted to use another approach . I don't know it is correct or not. I returned livedate value from repository then I get in mutable live data . then assign it by get() to Livedata. finally using observer in fragment. not worked. it seem returns null value and not triggered by new value.

Repository:

```
   fun getReviewPlace(idPlace:String): LiveData<MutableList<CommentModel>>
    {
         val Reviews:MutableLiveData<MutableList<CommentModel>> = MutableLiveData()
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val requestReviews = ServiceBuilder.apiServiceFake.getReviewPlace(idPlace)
            if (requestReviews.isSuccessful)
            {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Reviews.value = requestReviews.body()
                }
            }
        }
        return Reviews
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
private var _Reviews:MutableLiveData<MutableList<CommentModel>> = MutableLiveData(mutableListOf())
val Reviews:LiveData<MutableList<CommentModel>> get () = _Reviews


fun getReviews(id:String)
{
    _Reviews.value=AllInfoRepository.getReviewPlace(id).value
}
```

Fragment:

```
        lateinit var myViewModel: allInfoViewModel
        myViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(allInfoViewModel::class.java)
        myViewModel.getReviews(myId)
        myViewModel.Reviews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { ReviewsList ->
         if(ReviewsList!=null) {
            RVReviews.adapter = RVAdapterCommentOutsideInfo(mycontext, ReviewsList, 2)
            }
          else{
          //it seems ReviewsList is always return null
          }
         })
```

Edit :I know I could return directly LiveData value to fragment Like this in viewModel:

```
fun getReviews(id:String)=AllInfoRepository.getReviewPlace(id)
```

then observer should be :

```
    myViewModel.getReviews(myId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { ReviewsList ->
        if(ReviewsList!=null) {
            RVReviews.adapter = RVAdapterCommentOutsideInfo(mycontext, ReviewsList, 2)
        }
    })
```

I want to know what is the reason that above method is not worked.

Comment: Start with debugging your code line by line using breakpoints. Will help you in long run.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to consume the value before completion of the task inside Coroutine.

```
_Reviews.value=AllInfoRepository.getReviewPlace(id).value
```

At this time, your live data `val Reviews:MutableLiveData<MutableList<CommentModel>> = MutableLiveData()` is null.